# Visual C++ can't open include file 'iostream'

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. I just started! I tried a code on Visual C++ 2010 Express version, but I got the following code error message.

```
------ Build started: Project: abc, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  ugo.cpp
c:\users\castle\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\abc\abc\ugo.cpp(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is the code:

```
// first.cpp -- displays a message

#include <iostream> // A PREPROCESSOR directive

int main(void) // Function header
{              // Start of a function body
  using namespace std;
  cout << "Come up and C++ me sometime.\n";  // Message

  // Start a new line
  cout << "Here is the total: 1000.00\n";
  cout << "Here we go!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This has to be an installation problem of some kind.

Comment: FYI, you should avoid using tabs in your code. They are very difficult to deal with when formatting on Q&A sites like this. Use spaces instead.

Comment: I assume your include path includes the VC include directory (under program files). However, when installing VC did you select the native files?

Comment: Hi david, this is what i have in my include path : Program files (x86) > Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 > VC > include > srv.h

Comment: @ David. How do i select the native file when installing VC?

Comment: not a direct answer, but by changing to CLion you can forget about such issues

Answer (score 13):

**Some things that you should check:**

- Check the include folder in your version of Visual Studio (*in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio xx.x\VC\include", check for the file which you are including, `iostream`, make sure it's there*).
- Check your projects *Include Directories* in <Project Name> → *Properties* → *Configuration Properties* → *VC++ Directories* → *Include Directories* (it should look like this: `$(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSdkDir)include;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include;`)
- Make sure that you selected the correct project for this code
  (menu *File* → *New* → *Project* → *Visual C++* → *Win32 Console Application*)
- Make sure that you don't have `<iostream.h>` anywhere in your code files, Visual Studio doesn't support that (*in the same project, check your other code files, .cpp and .h files for* *<iostream.h>* *and remove it*).
- Make sure that you don't have more than one `main() function in your project code files (*in the same project, check your other code files, .cpp and .h files for the*` main()` *function and remove it or replace it with another name*).

**Some things you could try building with:**

- Exclude `using namespace std;` from your `main()` function and put it after the include directive.
- Use `std::cout` without `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @ Secko : what do i check in these lines: 
    Check the include folder in your version of VS.
    Check you projects Include Directories in <Project Name> > Properties > Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories
    Make sure that you selected the correct project for this code (console application)
    Make sure that you don't have <iostream.h> anywhere in your code files (VS doesn't support that).
    Make sure that you don't have more than one main() function in your project code files.
I am really new

Answer (score 13):

Replace

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

with

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
```

Comment: What if you didn't want to use the std namespace?

Comment: @sparkyShorts so when we usually code in C/C++ the usual standard that is to be followed is to not write "using namespace XXX" to avoid confusion when someone is debugging the code. Instead, we directly use the namespace name and call its library function. e.g. std::cout, std::cin, std::vector<void*>, etc.

Comment: Using *.h for any header file is only recommended for external libraries to that of standard C++, so if you are including a standard C/C++ library, please avoid using ".h" as a suffix.

Comment: Exposing the whole namespace and on top of that for including a standard header sounds like a broken mess. I would check the other answers.

Comment: This is wrong adding "using namespace std;" doesn't fix the missing iostream error. Also you should not add using namespaces there.

Comment: It looks wrong (both of your comments are right), but it fixed this error for me and for others...

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact same problem in [Visual Studio 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2015). It looks like as of [Visual Studio 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2010) and later you need to include `#include "stdafx.h"` in all your projects.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

The above worked for me. The below did not:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

This also failed:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Comment: (For anyone passing) If this happens to you, disable precompiled headers.

Answer (score 4):

You are more than likely missing **$(IncludePath)** within *Properties* → *VC++ Directories* → *Include Directories*.

Adding this should make iostream and others visible again. You probably deleted it by mistake while setting up your program.

Answer (score 3):

If your include directories are referenced correctly in the VC++ project property sheet → *Configuration Properties* → *VC++ directories* → *Include directories*, the path is referenced in the macro *$(VC_IncludePath)*.

In my Visual Studio 2015 this evaluates to:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include"

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
```

That did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that your compiler and the resources installed around it were somehow incomplete. I recommend re-installing your compiler: it should work after that.

Comment: i have tried a number of times. Same outcome. I am considering using a different compiler. Please can you suggest anyone?

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I created an 'Empty' console application in [Visual Studio 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2015).  I recreated the application, leaving the 'Empty' box unchecked. It added all of the necessary libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Visual Studio is funny. When you're using the installer, you *must* checkbox a lot of options to bypass the .NET framework (somewhat) to make more C++ instead of [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) applications, such as the CLR options under desktop development... in the Visual Studio installer.... the difference is the C++ Win32 console project or a C++ CLR console project.

So what’s the difference? Well, I'm not going to list all of the files CLR includes, but since most good C++ kernels are in Linux... So CLR allows you to bypass a lot of the Windows .NET framework because Visual Studio was really meant for you to make applications in C#.

Here’s a C++ Win32 console project!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now here’s a C++ CLR console project!

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

Both programs do the same thing .... the CLR just looks more frameworked class overloading methodology, so Microsoft can great its own vast library you should familiarize yourself with if so inclined.

*[Keywords (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/keywords-cpp)*

Other things you'll learn from debugging to add for error avoidance:

```
#ifdef _MRC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have *Desktop Development with C++* installed.

I was experiencing the same problem, because I only had *Universal Windows Platform Development* installed.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix for small programs:

Add: `#include <cstdlib>`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my [Visual Studio 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2015) installed without selecting *C++ package*, and [Visual Studio 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2017) is installed with the *C++ package*. If I use Visual Studio 2015, opening a C++ project will show this error, and using Visual Studio 2017 will be no error.

Answer (score 1):

If you created an environment variable with the name **IncludePath**, try renaming it to something else.

This name will override **$(IncludePath)** inside project properties.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. I used this code (before *main();*) in [Visual Studio 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2022), and it turned OK:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message "**cannot open source file iostream**" typically occurs when the C++ compiler is unable to locate the standard input/output header file "iostream" during compilation.

## To resolve this issue, you can try the following:

1. Check if you have included the correct header file "iostream" in your C++ code using the #include directive.
   The correct syntax is:`#include <iostream>`
2. Check if you have installed a C++ compiler on your system. You can use a compiler like GCC, Clang, or Microsoft Visual C++ to compile your code.
3. Check if the include path for your C++ compiler is set correctly. The include path tells the compiler where to find header files like "iostream". If the path is not set correctly, the compiler may not be able to find the file.
4. If you are using an IDE like Visual Studio, try creating a new project and copying your code into it. This can sometimes resolve issues with project settings.
5. If none of the above steps work, you can try reinstalling your C++ compiler or using a different compiler.

I hope this helps you resolve the issue.