# VS2019 Suddenly unable to find Cpp basic header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

en----First of all, I created this project on Win7, and the related configuration is also configured on win7 (I configured OpenGL, Boost, QT in the project, and I also performed the same configuration in win10), but when I put When the project was uploaded to GitHub, and then the project was copied on the win10 computer and continued to develop, there was an inexplicable error.

zh----首先, 这个项目是我在 Win7 上创建的, 相关配置也是在 win7 上先配置(我在项目中配置了 OpenGL, Boost, QT, 而且我在win10 中也进行了一模一样的配置), 但是当我把项目上传到 GitHub, 再在 win10 的电脑上把项目复制下来的时候继续开发的时候, 就出现了很莫名其妙的错误.

[When writing the code, you can obviously find the file(在编写代码时明明可以找到文件)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JREJ4.png)

[But after writing, it prompts that no file was found(可是写完后却提示没有找到文件)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2u4c3.png)

How can i solve this problem (请问我应该怎样解决这个问题)

Comment: I'm a complete stranger to this issue. However, Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11713893/7314877

Comment: Unfortunately, I rebuilt a small project. The cpp table quasi library displayed in the project is correct, but this project downloaded from GitHub can not find the cpp table quasi library. The process can be promptly reminded, super depressed ...

Comment: And now when I open this project on win7, everything shows normal   (T_T)